# NullPointerException When retrieving Value From Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a `database` Related App. When I Run My App gets automatically Stopped . In The Log cat It Show NullPointerException on Datachange .

Here is My Firebase Code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ezzeearnRef = rootRef.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long points = dataSnapshot.child("Points").getValue(Long.class);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(points));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    ezzeearnRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
}
```

Comment: App stopped working when my points = 0;

Comment: Ok. I am posting :D

Comment: check this screenshot :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciWC8.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are getting datasnapshot as null then also you are going access value of datasnapshot please write following line and check,

Replace your following code:

```
long points = dataSnapshot.child("Points").getValue(Long.class);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(points));
```

with following

```
if(dataSnapshot.exist()){
long points = dataSnapshot.child("Points").getValue(Long.class);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(points));}
```

and try.

Comment: And Points = 0 ; In my database

Comment: Can you post your database screenshot, And one more thing is app crashing when are you changing the value in the database or at initialization time?

Comment: its always crash . I tried by changing my points value . But not works :(

Comment: I am not asking for every time but it crashing when you start your app or initialization time?

Comment: yes. When i start the App. Wait i am giving a screenshot .

Comment: Change long to `Long`

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thanks Buddy :D . Its Now not showing error. Does it will works Same?

Comment: Yes!  No problem

Comment: If you are posting your database screenshot then we can check what actual problem,